# Server reports a ZeroWindow but there's no data in the receive buffer

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp, wireshark

I have a LINUX based server application that reports a TCP ZeroWindow on a socket connection to indicate that it is closing the receiving window.  This was confirmed with Wireshark and it should also be noted that window scaling is disabled.

The weird thing is that when looking at this connection with netstat, the connection shows the following:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.201:1344          192.168.0.101:35340         ESTABLISHED
```

The reason why I find this weird, is that the Recv-Q reports a value of 0, which means that it can receive more data, but yet the connection still reports a ZeroWindow indicating to the client not to send anything.

Because of this, the connection gets stuck in this state where no data flows anymore except the client that regularly sends special probe segments to the server. The purpose of these probes is to prompt the server to send back a segment containing the current window size; however, the window never reopens.

With this said, I was looking for an explanation of how the connection could get stuck in this state: ZeroWindow with Recv-Q also zero.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the server has decided that it is finished reading data and has called [shutdown(., SHUT_RD)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/shutdown.htm) on the socket. This should not send an RST yet to the client, as the server is still allowed to send data. The linux implementation might set the window size to 0 after the `shutdown()`, as the process has indicated it won't read any more data anyway (just an assumption, i never tries if linux really behaves that way). If you can reproduce the issue, try `strace`ing the server process before the connection enters this state.